# How to call the same class combined with another class using "this"?

Tags: jquery, class, this

HTML

```
<div class="header link1">Lorem</div>
<div class="header link2">Ipsum</div>

<div class="footer link1"></div>
<div class="footer link2"></div>
```

I want the contents of the divs 'header' to be copied to the divs 'footer', then we can do:

jQuery

```
$('.footer.link1').append($('.header.link1').text());
$('.footer.link2').append($('.header.link2').text());
```

But i wanna do like this:

jQuery

```
$('.link1, .link2, .link3, .link4, .link5').each(function(){
$('.footer'.this).append($('.header'.this).text());
});
```

Comment: is this happening in some kind of event?

Comment: Do you want it to see `link1` in the header div and automatically add the text to the footer div that also has `link1` as a class?

Comment: Exatly Archer, but I need to do this for various 'links' so I would do as the example I mentioned last, using the 'this' method

Comment: guys, thanks but none of these solutions solve my problem. Is there any way to call $('.footer.link2') like $('.link2').hasClass('.footer')? I just need a way to do something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach, working with only class names for `.link` elements, not the jQuery/DOM elements themselves:

```
$(['.link1',  '.link2', '.link3', '.link4', '.link5']).each(function(i, class_selector){
    $('.footer' + class_selector).append($('.header' + class_selector).text());
});
```

If you would like to complicate things by doing trough all the DOM elements (there might be good reason to go this route), then:

```
$('.link1, .link2, .link3, .link4, .link5').each(function(){
    if ( ! $(this).hasClass('header') ) return;
    var $tmpElement = $(this).clone();
    $tmpElement.removeClass('header');
    var class_selector = '.' + $tmpElement.attr('class').split(' ').join('.');
    $('.footer' + class_selector).append($('.header' + class_selector).text());
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

JSFiddles:

- http://jsfiddle.net/cek125i/wLujh/
- http://jsfiddle.net/cek125i/wLujh/1/

Comment: Is there any way to call $('.footer.link2') like $(this).hasClass('.footer')? I just need a way to do something like that. or $('.footer' + this) where 'this' is the called class

Comment: "I just need a way to do something like that. or $('.footer' + this) where 'this' is the called class" - that is exactly what my example does, isn't is? Both examples. What error are you getting?

Comment: $.each(['...'], function(i, class_selector){

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. The way you put in your first example didnt work well when applied. But when inverted as in example above it worked. I dont know why this worked and I dont know if you made ​​a mistake or if it is indifferent. In this case, I'll mark your answer as correct, but I suggest you fix it in your example.

Comment: @LGVentura you are right, there were problems with the second example, see corrected answer. I prefer the first solution, though. Also I have made JSFiddles for both solutions, see links. The second solution can be shortened a bit but I left it like this for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have multiple classes it makes it a little harder - this solution requires you to keep the classes in that order.  I just get all `.footer` elements, then append the text from the relevant `.header` element using the [.append(function()](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-functionindex--html) method

```
$('.footer').append(function(){
    return $('.header.'+this.classList[1]).text();
});
```

- This is assuming you will keep the .link1,.link2 as the second class because i'm using .classList to access the second class

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KEYCP/)</kbd>

Or using a more cross browser way

```
$('.footer').append(function(){
    return $('.header.'+this.className.split(' ')[1]).text();
});
```

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NTV2A/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.link1, .link2, .link3, .link4, .link5').each(function(){
if($(this).hasClass("header"))
{
  var classes = this.className.split(' ');
    $(".footer." + classes[1]).html($(this).text());

}
});
```

This is work OR

```
$('.link1, .link2, .link3, .link4, .link5').each(function(){

  var classes = this.className.split(' ');
    $(".footer." + classes[1]).html($(".header."+ classes[1]).text());


});
```

Comment: Is there any way to call $('.footer.link2') like $(this).hasClass('.footer')? I just need a way to do something like that. or $('.footer' + this) where 'this' is the called class